# Moved the Python installation - python runs, but ipython, flask, juypter, oldvba do not run - error in launcher

Tags: python, python-3.x

Moved my python installation to a new folder to eliminate space from username path

Updated the PATH variable to reflect the changes.

Re-run pip which fixed itself.

Running any thing like ipython, olevba, jupyter, oledir returns similar to

```
   Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python\Python39\Scripts\oledir.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've been through the Windows 10 registry and amended several obvious errors but I still can't fathom what else I am missing.

Ideas please.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried reinstalling those?

Comment: The path these processes use is the same path of python when you installed it for the first time. I don't know if you could fix this in Windows, but on Linux, to remove the cached paths, we could use something like `hash -r`. Try reinstalling them.

Comment: Tried pip install --upgrade ipython which install the upgrade but running ipython still produces same error message.

Answer (score 1):

In the end ran a pip freeze > requirements.txt. Copied that somewhere safe.

Delete the entire Python directory

Downloaded and ran the Python install (and upgraded to 3.9.6) which recognized my preferred installation folder and installed accordingly.

Ran pip install -r requirements.txt (which seemed to copy most from cache elsewhere)

Everything now works.